# Does a gym's prestige change if you defeat only some of the opposing Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

Say a red team gym with 7000 Prestige has three Pokemon defending it, a 500 CP Golbat, a 700 CP Pinser, and a 1500 CP Snorlax.

As a blue team member you attack the gym and defeat the Golbat and the Pinser but the Snorlax takes out all your remaining Pokemon.

Will the gyms prestige go up, down, or be unchanged?

Comment: It will go down. I'm not sure how much off-hand, or I'd post an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The gyms prestige will go down if you can only defeat some of the Pokémon, but not as much as if you can defeat all of the Pokémon. If you can keep taking down a few Pokémon each time you attack a gym, you will continue to take away some of the prestige each time.

source- personal experience from taking down level 9+ gyms.

Comment: You need so many potions to do this... level 9 is crazy.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf it takes a bit of time yeah, good thing I have a strong vaporeon though.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf get a friend to help, you can take down 10 Pokemon using 2 or 3 each (so about 5 total). Especially easy if you dodge well since it effectively has double damage and half health.

Answer (score 7):

Prestige of gym will go down if you defeat at least one defending pokemon, e.g. the first in line.

Thus, stack your team for the fight accordingly - be sure your line up will  beat the first.

Note; the autogenerated suggestion is not always the best line up.

Depending on the CP of your pokemon's vs the defending pokemon the amount of prestige lost and XP won will vary.